# How does the browser determine which element will be pushed to the right most?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using bootstrap's CSS style pull-right.

I want to understand how the browser determines which element will be the right-most and which one will be to the left?

i.e.

```
a b
```

versus

```
b a
```

Html looks like:

```
<div class="pull-right">
a
</div>
<div class="pull-right">
b
</div>
```

Comment: If both the div class are called `pull-right` the first one called in the document will be the first one to be pulled to the right if that class has the css properties on it.

Comment: I would think that reading the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/float) (_How floated elements are positioned_) or trying it yourself would give you the answer - Is there anything specific you don't understand that isn't explained there?

Comment: From that documentation it states "It is shifted to the left, or right, until it touches the edge of its containing box, or another floated element". Whichever element is first in the document will be floated first, making it the right-most element.